# My VC++ code fail to create a directory

Tags: winapi

I am useing windows 8.1. I have called an API CreateDirectory in my code. but it return failed. I have also get last error code using GetLastError.
my code is here. I get Error code 3. please help me where my error is. Sorry if any point is incomplete/

```
SYSTEMTIME sysTime;
GetLocalTime(&sysTime);

CString sFullPath;

sFullPath.Format("%s\\%d", sRecPath, sysTime.wYear); 

BOOL bRes = CreateDirectory(sFullPath, NULL);
int nErrorCode = GetLastError();
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are checking for errors incorrectly. As stated in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855.aspx), failure is indicated by the return value. Only if `bRes` is false is the value returned by `GetLastError` meaningful. So you should write:

```
if CreateDirectory(...)
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
```

Do note also that `GetLastError` returns an unsigned `DWORD` and not an `int`.

Assuming that `CreateDirectory` really does fail and the error code of `3` is accurate, that error code is `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`, described like this:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

Most likely that means that some part of the path specified in `sFullPath` does not exist. Note that `CreateDirectory` will not create a directory tree for you. It will only create a new directory object in an existing directory.

For instance, suppose that you are trying to create a directory like this:

```
CreateDirectory("C:\\ParentDir1\\ParentDir2\\MyNewDir", NULL)
```

Now, if `C:\ParentDir1\ParentDir2` already exists, then `CreateDirectory` will succeed. However, if `C:\ParentDir1\ParentDir2` does not exist already, then `CreateDirectory` will fail, and `GetLastError` will return `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND`.

This is even called out explicitly in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855.aspx) which states that the function will fail and the error code will be `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` if:

> One or more intermediate directories do not exist; this function will only create the final directory in the path.

You will be able to make progress by inspecting the value of `sFullPath`.

I do wonder how closely you read the documentation of this function. My bonus free piece of advice is to make sure that you read documentation carefully. Read it twice if that helps you take it in.

Comment: Good. You might consider accepting the answer, which I mention since you are new here and may not know our customs.